# Bootstrap columns: put middle column on a separate row on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with columns on bootstrap, I don't find how resolves my problem.

I would like it to look like its on pc :
[image]

and on mobile :
[image]

with the following row and columns,
someone has an idea how doing it ?

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="col-sm-4">
     1
     </div>
     <div class="col-6">
     2
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
     3
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that you want to use this layout with?

Comment: With something like it,
`<div class="container">
     <div class="col-sm-4">
     1
     </div>
     <div class="col-6">
     2
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
     3
     </div>
</div>`

Comment: Just use these classes for your desired query                                                               
<div class="container d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the order using the Bootstrap [order classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#reordering) `order-*` and `order-sm-*`.

In your example:

- Column 1 - we don't need to give this a class as it's always in the position it was created in.
- Column 2 is `order-sm-2 order-3` so it appears 2nd on screens bigger than 576px, and 3rd on all others.
- Column 3 is`order-sm-3 order-2` so it appears 3rd on screens bigger than 576px, and 2nd on all others.

**Example with `sm` breakpoint:**

```css
.row div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-4"> 1 </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-6 order-sm-2 order-3"> 2 </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 order-sm-3 order-2"> 3 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Example with large breakpoint** using exactly the same classes except using a larger breakpoint, so you can compare the results in the snippet:

```css
.row div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-4 col-lg-4"> 1 </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-6 order-lg-2 order-3"> 2 </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 order-lg-3 order-2"> 3 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but now my div 3 is on my div 2 because the container have margin

Comment: @rmarquet21 This is why we ask for the code you are using! We can only make it work with the code you give us - we can't know what else you are doing :) I'm not sure what you mean by div 3 is "on" div 2, but adding margins to the Bootstrap grid classes  is tricky in general as it breaks their layout. If you use them, you need to make adjustments to the rest of the layout.